# How to use scikit-learn for Q&A chatbot

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, chatbot

I want to create a chatbot for question answering purposes. I have my set of questions and answers. I already got a bot that only uses nltk with keyword recognition, but it has its limits. I would like to use machine learning to have a better chatbot.
I know scikit-learn is the best available Python library for ML, but I just don't know how to use it. All the exemples on their website are more about data visualization and not for actual using. For example, [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-classification-plot-digits-classification-py) example is "quite close" to mine, in the meaning that we have a dataset and want to classify.

What I want is to know ho to create my own model, like the iris one we can find in a lot of ML examples for noobs, but with my Q&A set. For example, I could have a table referencing the category of the question, its length, number of keywords, which ones, etc, but I don't know to do it. Then, I'm not sure which algorithm to use (I thought of KNN) but more importantly how to train the model and then use it for questions from user input.

Thank you guys.

Comment: This type of question does not belong in SO mate. You are asking for a reference to a tutorial, and there are other forums where you can get this information. Good luck buddy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a chat bot instead of ML you can use Deep learning.
One of the ways to create a chat bot is using Tensorflow sequence to sequence model.
For this you need to have a data set which contains more than 100000 pairs of question and ans.The training data is basically to and from data.
You basically train your network to give Ans.
Original seq-2-seq Model was used to translate english to french.
[Original seq-2-seq Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/tutorials/seq2seq)

This is not a ruled based chat bot. There are two types of chat bot :
1)Ruled based
2)Not ruled based
Modern chat bot are somewhere in between the two.

For complete steps to make your own chatbot:
Follow these steps:
Type this in Your cmd:

```
    #This will download the retrain script Which will retrain inception_v3
    git clone --recursive https://github.com/daniel-kukiela/nmt-chatbot

    cd nmt-chatbot

    #This will install all the requirements like tensorFlow etc.
    pip install -r requirements.txt

    #This will start training your model based on your data set
    python train.py
```

Note:It take hours of processing to train Your data set.
The git repository comes with its own .to and .from file. Change the dataset put your own data set.
You can refer this link if you want to make a chatbot:
[Video Link](https://pythonprogramming.net/training-model-chatbot-deep-learning-python-tensorflow/)

Do tell if it worked :)

Comment: Unfortunately I have very sparse data, with less than 1,000 questions. But I found a Python library that works pretty well with my data for sentence matching: https://github.com/facebookresearch/pysparnn